# GROUP BY with string postfix

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a situation in which i need to GROUP records according to similar name but with having `_QA` at the end of the name.

Here is complete example.

I have one table named `project` which contains `name` which is `varchar(200)`,

Example for the entry into that table is as below,

```
id = 1
name = Project

id = 2
name= Project_QA
```

as you can see i have entry with same name with only `_QA` is difference.

Now i want to query that table to group both `Project` and `Project_QA` will be grouped as one same record.

For what i have tried.? Sorry geeks i do not found anything so i am asking it here.

**I do not want store procedure.**

**Edit**

Now i have working query as per answer received, now one final problem.

Now i have a table named `working` which track working hours, how can i join this table and get total working hour sum.

I have below query.

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        ROUND(
            TIME_TO_SEC(
                TIMEDIFF(
                    vv.end_date,
                    vv.start_date
                )
            ) / 3600
        ,2)) AS TotalHour,
    ( select name from project where id=vv.project_id )  AS ProjectName,
    ( select planned_hour from project where id=vv.project_id )  AS ProjectPlannedHour
FROM
    working vv
WHERE
    vv.project_id in(select id from project)
GROUP BY
    vv.project_id,
    IF(SUBSTR(ProjectName, -3)='_QA', LEFT(ProjectName, CHAR_LENGTH(ProjectName)-3), ProjectName)
ORDER BY
    TotalHour DESC
LIMIT 0, 100
```

Comment: have you tried `GROUP BY REPLACE(name,"_QA","")` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's quite easy with [string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) functions:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  project 
GROUP BY 
  IF(SUBSTR(name, -3)='_QA', LEFT(name, CHAR_LENGTH(name)-3), name);
```

-fiddle [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa952/1).

Comment: @DipeshParmar then can you provide a fiddle? (for me - that works well - see my fiddle)

Comment: Okay got it working...just one question...did it also work when i use join..?

Comment: @DipeshParmar i.e. in `ON` condition? Why not? Simply be aware that you'll probably get multiple join second table rows for 1 corresponding first table row.

Comment: got it working...just removed `vv.project_id,` group by and its working like charm......+10000000000000000000000000000000  for you...Thanks.